# Perl : Display perl variable awk sed echo

Tags: perl

When I am using below command directly its working fine but when I am trying to put this in perl script its giving lots of error.

```
my $calculate = `echo "$value" | awk -F "SP=" '{print $2}' | awk  -F ";" '{print $1}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/\,/\//g'`;
```

Data is like:

```
HM=Happy:man,1;SP=SAD:person,3;AP=Arrogant:personality,5;MD=Mad:Dynamic,9;PR=Power:raper,10;
```

I want output as

```
person/3
```

Comment: Why not do it in pure Perl?! That would probably be easier anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... Please advice how can i do in pure perl..

Comment: Show us some example input and expected output. Chances are it can be done with a single regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using a Perl regex pattern

```
my $calculate;
($calculate = $1) =~ tr~,~/~ if $value =~ /SP=[^:]*:([^;]*)/;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I am getting syntax error :syntax error at file.pl line 7, near "tr~,~/~r "

Comment: You have an old copy of Perl that doesn't support the `/r` modifier. Try it now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.20;

my $data
  = 'HM=Happy:man,1;SP=SAD:person,3;AP=Arrogant:personality,5;MD=Mad:Dynamic,9;PR=Power:raper,10;';

my %hash = map {m/(.*?)=(.*)$/} split( ';', $data );

if ( $hash{'SP'} =~ m/:(\w+),(\d+)$/ ) {
  my $result = $1 . '/' . $2;
  say $result;
}
```

```
person/3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Above code is giving blank value for $result.

Comment: Sorry it looks like its not going in this loop --->  if ( $hash{'SP'} =~ m/:(\w+),(\d+)$/ ) {

Comment: It works fine for me; it enters the if statement (which isn't a loop, BTW) and prints `person/3`.

Comment: Did you debug it and have a look at the contents of `%hash`? Or at least print `$hash{'SP'}`?